# Compiling custom SQLite for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to compile the [SQLite amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) source into my iPhone app (to give me access to the full-text searching functionality that isn't available in the iPhone-compiled version of the binary.

When I add sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h to a normal Carbon C app template, it compiles just fine (with a single warning about an unused variable), but when I try compiling it in my iPhone project I get a number of errors relating to missing function declarations. I'm able to solve these problems by explicitly including ctype.h, but it's a little strange.

However, even after it builds it fails on linking with the following error:

```
"_sqlite3_version", referenced from:
_sqlite3_version$non_lazy_ptr in sqlite3.0
symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I assume that it's something in the iPhone app's build settings, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a Carbon C app template for iPhone deployment?

Comment: I'm not. I just wanted to see if it would compile anywhere -- i.e., if the iPhone project's settings were causing the problems -- so I figured that basic Carbon C template would be the least likely to interfere.

Comment: (and, incidentally, I was right, as it compiled just fine)

Comment: Ah, ok, I misread it. I am using the sqlite3 amalgamation on an iPhone project as well and I haven't had any issues with it not compiling.

Comment: That's what all of the references online that I've found have been saying -- just drop in the two files and you're good to go. Alas...

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm curious as to what the problem was...

Comment: I did, actually. It was that, as the linker was trying to tell me, sqlite3_version wasn't defined somehow. It's defined in several places throughout the (totally impossible to follow) amalgamation file, so I guess somehow #ifdef and #ifndef directives were confused and it was never getting defined. I manually added a line and it worked just fine. 

Strange though, no?

Comment: Yeah, quite! BTW, I ended up getting rid of the warning as well by moving the declaration of err to under the #ifdef debug or whatever. It seemed to me like it was probably meant to be there anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with this steps:

1. xcode menu -> project -> new target -> static library -> target name: SQLite
2. drop SQLite amalgamation source into the project, now you can select the target, choose SQLite
3. xcode menu -> project -> edit active target -> tab General -> Direct Dependencies -> add SQLite
4. tab General -> Linked Libraries -> add your SQLite

Comment: I ended up doing a variation of this, following the directions here: http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/

Worked quite well.

Comment: @makdad that link appears to be broken

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do this using the amalgamation and dumped it straight into my project without having to do the linking catlan suggested (I'm not saying it's a bad idea, merely it's possible to do in the main project).

I didn't need to edit anything (except for adding the necessary FTS define for the text searching) and compiled error free. Check your build settings and ensure '-sqlite3' isn't in your Other Linking Flags.

Answer (score 0):

That type of error usually means a missing framework.

1. Right- or control-click on your Project's *Frameworks* folder.
2. Select *Add > Existing Framework...*
3. Go to: *Macintosh HD > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > Developer > SDKs > iPhoneOS2.2sdk > usr > lib* and select *libsqlite3.dylib*
4. Rebuild your project

That should take care of it, I think. You may need to add a similar library for running on the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: But if I do that, it's going to link against the built-in SQLite library, right? Whereas I want to use my custom compiled one (because it has features that the built-in one doesn't).

Comment: I don't know that you can do that. I have a feeling Apple won't like it. I could be wrong though

Comment: @bdotdub - you definitely can do it - and why would apple care? it's not like he's trying to replace the system version, just compile in a new version used by his application. it's quite a standard practice.

Comment: Why does he want the iOS build of SQLite as well?