# Spatialite for iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, exc-bad-access, spatialite

in a past few days, I've been trying to use Spatialite with iOS. I have tried many things, but none of them worked. I have made best progress with SpatialDBKit, but it always fails when I run the application (with example from SpatilDBKit webpage) on this statement:

```
sqlite3_auto_extension ((void (*)(void)) init_spatialite_extension);
```

which is located in function spatialite_init in file spatialite_init.c. There is EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, which I don't understand much.
I have also tried solution with libspatialite-ios, but this is rather outdated and it doesn't work anymore.
Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to compile spatialite for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793970/how-to-compile-spatialite-for-ios)

Comment: I saw this question and I tried all advices mentioned there, but I have problem which wasn't described there.