# How to use "Spatialite" database extension in Swift/Objective-C on Xcode 11?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sqlite, spatialite

I wanted to use GIS features using spatial queries to sqlite.

I tried below possible methods which are outdated:

1. [static library of spatialite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863757/6499731)
2. [spatialite pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/spatialite)
3. [SpatialDBKit pod](https://github.com/andreacremaschi/SpatialDBKit)

Tried to use above possible methods but end up with many build errors, and there is no recent commits on those pods.

It will be appreciated if I get any help on it to support iOS.

Below is the build error:

> Implicit declaration of function 'virtualdbf_extension_init' is
>   invalid in C99