# Find nearby locations in a given region

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, mkmapview, coordinates

I have a table in the SQLite database with 4,000 locations, including latitude and longitude. Based on information from the region provided by **MKCoordinateRegion** class, how can I get the places that are located in this region from the map? Is It Possible?

First I tried using *Haversine formula*, but what I did was just sort the places closest to the center of the map. But I want places that are located in a region of the map. Or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the max/min values for latitude and longitude from your `MKMapView` by accessing the region attribute:

```
MKCoordinateRegion *mapRegion = myMap.region;
```

You can then access the maximum and minimum values as follows:

```
maxLatitude = mapRegion.center.latitude + mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2;
minLatitude = mapRegion.center.latitude - mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2;

maxLongitude = mapRegion.center.longitude+ mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2;
minLongitude = mapRegion.center.longitude- mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2;
```

Hope this helps! If you're storing your data in Core Data, an `NSSet`, or an `NSArray`, you can then use an `NSPredicate` to filter out the results that meet the above criteria.

Here's the documentation for your [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) and an [`MKCoordinateRegion`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find all the places in a rectangular region?

Simply set up your query as such:

```
find all locations where latitude > mapMinLat
                     and latitude < mapMaxLat
                     and longitude > mapMinLon
                     and longitude < mapMaxLon
```

where the edges of your map are mapMinLat, mapMaxLat, mapMinLon, mapMaxLon.

If you're looking for a polygonal region, you'll need to use a more advanced algorithm.

Comment: Exactly, I want all the places in a rectangular region. Based on your code, how can I get the max-min values from map?

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea if this will solve your problem, but [SpatialLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) is a 3rd party library that says:

> SpatiaLite is an open source library intended to extend the SQLite
>   core to support fully fledged Spatial SQL capabilities.

Looking at the list of functions there is a whole section named `SQL functions that implement spatial operators`

Rolling your own sqlite code has been answered many times on SO, for example [Compiling custom SQLite for an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823706/compiling-custom-sqlite-for-an-iphone-app)