# PhoneGap, SQLite and full-text search

Tags: sqlite, cordova, fts3, fts4

We are trying to scope out a project that has a relatively sophisticated search function. For instance it needs to search variations of words -- with "legal" and "legally" treated the same.

I believe the SQLite full-text extensions (FTS3, FTS4) will do everything we need, but I don't know if that's an option.  Has anyone successfully used SQLite with FTS3 or FTS4 in a PhoneGap application?

If not, does anyone know of any robust alternatives that will work in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sqlite build in iOS does not support FTS. You have compile your own version with support for FTS3/FTS4 and include it in your project. Then, in PhoneGap, use an [SQLite plugin](https://github.com/ApplicationCraft/PGSQLitePlugin) and you have a SQLite DB with FTS.

Comment: I see.  That makes sense (or as much as it could make sense without experience compiling a custom version of SQLite in PhoneGap).  A couple questions: 1) have you actually done this (with FTS), or is this theoretical? 2) would I still be able to use the online PhoneGap Build service (I'm guessing not).

Comment: 1) Yes, I have done it. It was actually simpler than initially thought. You have to include the SQLite amalgamation in your project. A good starting point is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823706/compiling-custom-sqlite-for-an-iphone-app). Then you have to enable the Build Settings, Preprocessor Settings SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3.

2) No, you won't be able to use the PhoneGap Build service.